# Extend User Info Bar?

Tags: 2013

In SDL Tridion 2013, users have a User Info Bar (aka personal information center) that shows notifications and tasks. Is it possible to extend or change the subject and action text that displays under tasks?

Use case would be changing the text box height or possibly allowing rich text (e.g. a link to an item in the CME).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, official name for personal information center is "User Info Bar" (`UserInfoBar` control). And this control is not really extensible. But here are some hints:

- The notification you see in `UserInfoBar` is actually a message of specific type - `WorkflowNotificationMessage`
- The height of notification message will adopt to the amount of inner text content
- `Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.messagecenter` group of CME Editor configuration file contains reference to "WorkflowNotificationMessage.js" file. This file has implementation for `$messages.registerWorkflowNotificationMessage` method, which accepts title and description properties. So you can extend group (via default groups extensibility mechanism) by adding new file to it. This file could contain new `registerWorkflowNotificationMessage` with extra logic and call to original method.

Be aware, that this is not really supported, but allows to avoid modification of the original files, which is forbidden at all!

Comment: +1 and accepted. I didn't know the height expanding to the text--that addresses the main concern of it seeming "too small." Thanks for the breakdown of the parts. I'll update the question to match the right term.

Answer (score 9):

I've not had a play with this area of the CME GUI but in the past I've written GUI extensions that can add some additional javascript into the browser.   This javascript can add some CSS information to elements (where you need to change heights) or the text contained with in elements inject a bit of javascript.

Regarding your use-case, I'm sure you could use anquilla to grab the content of a component and put the text into the element area you are interested in.

If that's a solution for you (I'm assuming you've done some homework and had a look into how it's implemented / have some ideas) let me know and i'll update my answer with some code samples.